# SailsJS Mongodb timeout

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have this controller code in my sails app:

```
let userId = req.body.userId;
User.findOne({ id: userId })
  .then((user) => {
    console.log('User found:', user);
    return res.ok('It worked!');
  }).catch((err) => {
    sails.log.error('indexes - error', err);
    return res.badRequest(err);
  });
```

When I start my server it works, but then after some times (~5min) it stops working and I end up having the following error message:

```
web_1  | Sending 400 ("Bad Request") response: 
web_1  |  Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
web_1  | MongoError: server 13.81.244.244:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ETIMEDOUT"}
web_1  |     at null.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:213:40)
web_1  |     at g (events.js:260:16)
web_1  |     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
web_1  |     at emit (events.js:172:7)
web_1  |     at null.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:119:12)
web_1  |     at g (events.js:260:16)
web_1  |     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
web_1  |     at emit (events.js:172:7)
web_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:154:93)
web_1  |     at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
web_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
web_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
web_1  |     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
web_1  |     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
web_1  |     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:466:17)
web_1  | 
web_1  | Details:  MongoError: server 13.81.244.244:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ETIMEDOUT"}
```

The DB is still up at this point, and looking at the logs, everything seems fine on this side:

```
2017-03-23T16:45:51.664+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 13.81.243.59:51558 #7811 (39 connections now open)
2017-03-23T16:45:51.664+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7811] received client metadata from 13.81.253.59:51558 conn7811: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.25" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-62-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v4.7.3, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.9" }
2017-03-23T16:45:51.723+0000 I ACCESS   [conn7811] Successfully authenticated as principal username on dbname
```

My `connections.js` hook looks like this:

```
module.exports.connections = {
  sailsmongo: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    host      : process.env.MONGODB_HOST,
    port      : 27017,
    user      : process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME,
    password  : process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD,
    database  : process.env.MONGODB_DBNAME
  },
}
```

and in `package.json`:

```
"sails": "~0.12.4",
"sails-mongo": "^0.12.1",
```

**Notes:**

Among the unconfirmed possible sources of misbehavior, I see:

- the app is dockerized
- I have a query that takes quite some time (~1/2min) and call several child processes, so I'd suspect some memory leak out there, though this is still unconfirmed!

Any idea on this?

---

EDIT:

After some digging, I have the impression, looking at the DB logs that sails/waterline opens a new connection on each query while it should be plugged once and kept alive. This would be the cause of the issue.

From this, I decided to try along Mongoose, and bingo, in Mongoose it works like a charm.

I'm guessing this is a Sails/Waterline bug occurring then, though I'm not clear on how to reproduce this correctly.

Anyway, I'm now moving my app from Waterline to Mongoose.

Comment: Have you checked for any db server system startup logs / the mongodb daemon start logs? It may happen that if the system/mongo daemon is restarted, the app server will give up the connection with ETIMEDOUT, if no reply is obtained from the db server.

Comment: In the end, I unplugged Waterline using Mongoose instead, which works without issues. My guess is that there *is* an issue in the Sails-Mongo ORM adapter but I don't have enough info to make a reproductible bug...